# Python - bug - deleting elements from a list

Tags: python, list

In an exercise I'm supposed to have a program that asks for multiple inputs and the program should delete the largest and smallest n numbers.

My attempt:

```
def outliers(lst, n):

    new = sorted(lst)

    for i in range(0, n):
        del new[i]
        del new[len(new) - i - 1]

    return new

def main():
    lst = []
    n = int(input("Enter a non-zero number: "))
    while n != 0:
        lst.append(n)
        n = int(input("Enter a non-zero number: "))

    print(f"the list without the 2 outliers are: {outliers(lst, 2)}")

main()
```

Bug:

```
Enter a non-zero number: 1
Enter a non-zero number: 2
Enter a non-zero number: 5
Enter a non-zero number: 8
Enter a non-zero number: 9
Enter a non-zero number: 0
the list without the 2 outliers are: [8]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The program should return a list [5]. I tried to run parts of the program, i know the error must be that for loop that I'm using. But it seems correct to me. Can someone tell me why it's not working the way it should?

Comment: After you delete the 0th element and then try to delete the 1th element you actually delete a different element than you think.

Answer (score 2):

As you delete element at the beginning, the other elements move forward, just use the slice notation

```
def outliers(lst, n):
    return sorted(lst)[n:-n]


print(outliers([1, 2, 5, 8, 9], 2))  # [5]
print(outliers([1, 2, 5, 8, 9], 1))  # [2, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def outliers(lst, n):

    new = sorted(lst)

    for i in range(0, n):
        del new[0]
        del new[len(new) - 1]

    return new
```

we should always delete new[0], because original first elem had gone

Comment: not sure `-0` is required ;)

Comment: replace i to 0; make it simple to understand